How do I gain a PPL for small crafts such as a C172?
I'm heavily inclined towards rocketry and aviation, although I do not plan of pursuing aviation in my future (but instead rocketry) I'd love to be able to fly small aircrafts such as the C172 or a small Piper. As of now I'm only 14, but I'd like to know what future qualifications I might require in order to operate a C172 and what I'd need to study. (I do understand that this requires quite a budget).

It varies a lot by your country.

Depending on your location there may also be a lot cheaper options than PPL license. Are you interested in hearing about these?

This is easily answerable by Google, but also by visiting your local flight school.

I'm answering for how it is in India because I think from your profile that you're in India.

First Steps
You can start flying training at 18 years old for a Student Pilot License (SPL). To get a full Private Pilot License (PPL), you also need to be 18.
Qualifications and Training
You must have completed 10th standard (secondary school) at a minimum.
A 12th-grade education (higher secondary) with physics and mathematics is required for pursuing a Commercial Pilot License (CPL).
Student Pilot License (SPL)
First step towards becoming a pilot.
You’ll undergo basic training and take a few written exams. The SPL allows you to fly under the supervision of a certified flight instructor.
Requirements:

Pass a medical examination (Class 2 Medical by DGCA).
Clear a basic written test covering aviation knowledge.

Private Pilot License (PPL)
After obtaining your SPL, you can start working toward a PPL, which allows you to fly solo or carry passengers (but not for commercial purposes).
Requirements:

At least 40 to 60 hours of flying time, which includes dual flight
instruction (with an instructor) and solo flight time.
Ground school courses covering subjects like air regulations,
meteorology, air navigation, and aircraft technical knowledge.
Clear written exams conducted by the Directorate General of Civil
Aviation (DGCA).
Pass a practical flying test with a DGCA examiner.

You should be academically excellent and have good grades.
Budget Considerations
This is only a rough estimate I could find...

Flying school fees: Between ₹20 lakhs to ₹1cr for the PPL course,
depending on the school and how many flying hours you complete.
Medical exams, ground school, and exam fees: Around ₹1
lakh to ₹5 lakhs
Miscellaneous fees: upto ₹5 lakhs

Most flight schools aren't in urban areas so you need to pay for accommodation too, which is an additional amount here.
In India recreational flying is not too common and almost all pilots get a PPL only to advance to the CPL and make this their career.
Well-known flight schools
There's many flight schools in India that cater to many budget options and offer great services.
You can find them according to your convenience.

Although this answer is for India only, this doesn't exactly vary to much. You can get even more exact details by calling a flight school.
